# Compiler issues with a Queue program and templates

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

I'm having some trouble implementing templates in a c++ queue I'm writing. If you guys could help me sort through some compiler issues, I'd love it!

Here's my compiler output:

> In file included from a7_main.cpp:3:0: Queue.h: In member function
>   TYPE Queue::pushAndPop(TYPE):
>
> Queue.h:33:25: warning: name lookup of x changed [enabled by
>   default]
>
> Queue.h:27:28: warning:   matches this x under ISO standard
>   rules [enabled by  default]
>
> Queue.h:30:11: warning:   matches this x under old rules
>   [enabled by default]
>
> Queue.h: At global scope:
>
> Queue.h:45:23: error: invalid use of template-name Queue without
>   an argument list
>
> Queue.h: In copy constructor Queue::Queue(Queue&) [with
>   TYPE = V2,  Queue = Queue]:
>
> a7_main.cpp:56:19:   instantiated from here
>
> Queue.h:41:5: error: no matching function for call to
>   Queue::pushAndPop(int)
>
> Queue.h:41:5: note: candidate is:
>
> Queue.h:27:28: note: TYPE Queue::pushAndPop(TYPE) [with TYPE =
>   V2]
>
> Queue.h:27:28: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from
>   int to V2

I've tried making sense of these warnings and errors, but it's got me in a rut. Here's my code:

```
#if !defined QUEUE_SIZE
#define QUEUE_SIZE 30
#endif
using namespace std;

template <class TYPE> class Queue
{
 private:
  TYPE *array;
 public:
  Queue(Queue& other);
  Queue();
  ~Queue();
  Queue& operator=(Queue other);
  TYPE pushAndPop(TYPE x);
};

template <class TYPE> Queue<TYPE>::Queue()
{
  array=new TYPE[size];
}

template <class TYPE> Queue<TYPE>::~Queue()
{
  delete [] array;
}

template <class TYPE> TYPE Queue<TYPE>::pushAndPop(TYPE x)
{
  TYPE item = array[0];
  for(int x = 0; x<QUEUE_SIZE-1; x++){
    array[x]= array[x+1];
  }
  array[QUEUE_SIZE-1] = x;
  return item;
}

template <class TYPE> Queue<TYPE>:: Queue(Queue& other)
{
  int x;
  for(x=0; x<QUEUE_SIZE;x++){
    array[x] = other.pushAndPop(0);
  }
}

template <class TYPE> Queue& Queue<TYPE>:: operator=(Queue other)
{
  int x;
  for(x=0; x<QUEUE_SIZE;x++){
    array[x] = other.pushAndPop(0);
  }
}
```

EDIT: Here's the calling code:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "Queue.h"

//----------------------------------------------------

#define START_ROW (20)
#define START_COL (20)
#define SLEEP_MICROSECONDS ((1.0 / 20.0) * 1000000.0)

//----------------------------------------------------

// Simple storage for a row, column pair.
struct V2 {
  int row, col;
};

//----------------------------------------------------

// Some of this ncurses code is, unfortunately, copied from
// the man page without full understanding.
void configureNcurses()
{
  initscr();
  cbreak();
  noecho();
  nonl();
  intrflush(stdscr, FALSE);
  keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
  nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);
  curs_set(0);
  start_color();
  init_pair(1, COLOR_RED, COLOR_BLACK);
  init_pair(2, COLOR_GREEN, COLOR_BLACK);
  init_pair(3, COLOR_YELLOW, COLOR_BLACK);
  init_pair(4, COLOR_BLUE, COLOR_BLACK);
  init_pair(5, COLOR_MAGENTA, COLOR_BLACK);
  init_pair(6, COLOR_CYAN, COLOR_BLACK);
  init_pair(7, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_BLACK);
}

//----------------------------------------------------

// Draw centipede with sequence of foreground colors, or with
// background color, depending on "erase" flag.
// (Pass centipede by value to exercise copy constructor.)
void drawCentipede(Queue<V2> centipede, bool erase)
{
  int drawCharacter;
  int colorNumber;
  V2 currentPosition, dummyPosition;
  Queue<V2> centipedeCopy;

  // Make a copy of centipede to be consumed during drawing.
  // (Exercises assignment operator.)
  centipedeCopy = centipede;

  // Prepare to draw or erase, as requested.
  if (erase)
    drawCharacter = ' ';
  else
    drawCharacter = ' ' | A_REVERSE;

  // Consume centipede copy to obtain data for drawing.
  for (int i = 0; i < QUEUE_SIZE; ++i) {
    colorNumber = 1 + (i % 7);
    currentPosition = centipede.pushAndPop(dummyPosition);
    attron(COLOR_PAIR(colorNumber));
    mvaddch(currentPosition.row, currentPosition.col,
            drawCharacter);
    attroff(COLOR_PAIR(colorNumber));
  }
}

//----------------------------------------------------

// Update position based on arrow key input.
void updatePosition(V2& position, int inputChar)
{
    switch (inputChar) {
    case KEY_UP:
      --position.row;
      break;
    case KEY_DOWN:
      ++position.row;
      break;
    case KEY_LEFT:
      --position.col;
      break;
    case KEY_RIGHT:
      ++position.col;
      break;
    default:
      // (Ignore all other keys.)
      break;
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------

main()
{
  Queue<V2> centipede;
  int currentDirection;
  int inputChar;
  V2 currentHead;

  // Configure ncurses.
  configureNcurses();

  // Fill queue (all centipede segments at start position).
  currentHead.row = START_ROW;
  currentHead.col = START_COL;
  for (int i = 0; i < QUEUE_SIZE; ++i)
    centipede.pushAndPop(currentHead);

  // Draw instructions and initial centipede.
  attron(COLOR_PAIR(2));
  mvaddstr(1, 3, "USE ARROW KEYS TO MOVE, CTRL-C TO QUIT");
  attroff(COLOR_PAIR(2));
  drawCentipede(centipede, false);
  refresh();

  // Process input until killed.
  currentDirection = KEY_RIGHT;
  while (true) {
    // Show current state, then check for input.
    usleep(SLEEP_MICROSECONDS);
    inputChar = getch();
    if (inputChar != ERR)
      currentDirection = inputChar;

    // When input received, erase old centipede.
    drawCentipede(centipede, true);

    // Then use new input to update centipede.
    updatePosition(currentHead, currentDirection);
    centipede.pushAndPop(currentHead);

    // Then draw new centipede, and refresh.
    drawCentipede(centipede, false);
    refresh();
  }

  // Clean up ncurses.  (Re-display cursor.)
  curs_set(1);
}

//----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: pushAndPop uses x as a parameter name and as a loop variable name - not a good idea at all. The other error refers to a use of that template which appears to be incorrect. You'll need to show the "calling" code.

Comment: Well, sorry the calling code is irrelevant. Hadn't read the error message correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
template <class TYPE> Queue<TYPE>::Queue()
{
  array=new TYPE[size];
}
```

What is `size`?

```
template <class TYPE> TYPE Queue<TYPE>::pushAndPop(TYPE x)
                                                   ^^^^^^
{
  ...
  for(int x = 0; ...) {
      ^^^^^
```

You've got conflicting names here. That's a bad idea. Name the parameter or the loop variable differently.

```
template <class TYPE> Queue<TYPE>:: Queue(Queue& other)
                                          ^^^^^^
```

What sort of `Queue` does this accept? If it's only `Queue<TYPE>`, you need to specify exactly that. If it could take other types, you'll need another template parameter (but that  doesn't make sense here).

```
template <class TYPE> Queue& Queue<TYPE>:: operator=(Queue other)
                      ^^^^^^                         ^^^^^
```

Same remark here, plus the parameter looks like it should be taken by (likely `const`) reference.

```
array[x] = other.pushAndPop(0);
                            ^
```

(Twice.) Unless `TYPE` is some sort of `int`, this doesn't make sense. You don't have a `pushAndPop` overload that takes an `int`.

If I understand your code correctly, both the copy constructor and the copy-assignment operator destroy their arguments. That's very surprising. The arguments should be taken by `const&` and only read from.